# Querying a common table expression in a loop using a separate rowset

Tags: mysql

[image]

I am tasked right now with developing a complicated MySQL search query that basically does the following:

1. Using a 'base table' in the database, expand on its entries to create the 'expanded table'. I have done this using a recursive common table expression.
2. Loop through a list of numbers and select entries in the expanded table that have a `mz1_monoisotopic` value within a small tolerance window (1 unit). I found how to make a rowset using the `VALUES` statement, but I do not know how to iterate through this list to query the expanded set and create new separated rowsets with the result.
3. Reduce these row sets down with an aggregate function, union them, split them again, and calculate scores.

In generate I can figure out the code for each individual part of this process but do not know how to combine them all into a single query. How can I iterate through a list like the following pseudocode?:

```
foreach(value in query_rowset)
{
    SELECT * FROM expanded_set AND PLACE IN SEPARATE ROWSET THAT I CAN USE LATER
}
```

I am new to MySQL and it seems like this would be some monstrous query with common table expressions and subqueries... but I do not know how to structure such a query. I made a schematic to try to help explain this... it is the red part that I am struggling with right now.

Thank you for any guidance

### Generating the expanded set

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
cte (id, parent, sequence, mz1_monoisotopic, MSO) AS
(
  SELECT 
        id,
        parent,
        sequence, 
        mz1_monoisotopic,
        0 AS MSO
  FROM 
        `1_plant_trypsin_dig` 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
        id,
        parent,
        sequence,
        `mz1_monoisotopic` + 15.999 AS `mz1_monoisotopic`,
        MSO + 1
  FROM 
        cte 
  WHERE 
        MSO < (CHAR_LENGTH(sequence) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE( sequence, 'M', '')))
)
```

### Generating the query set

```
VALUES ROW (1, 1100.251), ROW (2, 1325.661), ROW (3, 1854.271)
```

Comment: you lost me, as i don't understand whyt you trying to do with your loop. besides loops only exsit in stored procudures, Mysql and all rdms in general you see what your select must have then you join your tabkes(eventually with calculations) till you get all dataneeded in the from clause and then make more calculations to get your wanted results(which you haven't done) every cte is a small create table) so presents us with a [mre] and lets see fro  there

Comment: I need to iteratively query the expanded table and keep the results of each iteration separate, but I have no idea how to write an example of this

Comment: iterations are possible in stored procedures with cursors see for example https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/ the cursor can be you cte, but as i wrote before i really don-'t get what you trying to do

Comment: please add some sample data and final results for that sample data.  I doubt you actually want to use a loop of separate queries rather than just a very complex query doing the grouping and splitting.  please explain where your example 'VALUES' came from; is that showing the results of you manually finding the groups of values within a small tolerance window?  specifically show lots of examples of how that grouping works.  and you provide almost no information about your step 3

Comment: Ok I will repost a question, I thought that would be too much information but it turns out it is not enough! Thank you, I'll repost in a bit